# How do I create a loop that goes from line to line of an ArrayList splitting each line up?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, while-loop, split

I have a function that accesses a file and sets each line as a new string line in an arraylist. How do I make a loop that will go through each line and split the line where a "," is present such that it creates "columns."

Example:
the file contians the lines

```
a, 1, 3, b
3, 2, 5, 6
c, b, d, 4
```

the following will save each line as strings in an arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
while(input_file.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = input_file.nextLine();
    result.add(line);
}
```

from here I am kind of stumped. I know that the following bit of code will take the 1st line of the file "a, 1, 3, b" and split it into new strings in a new arraylist.

```
String foo = input_file.nextLine();
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(foo.split(",")));
```

is there a way to combine both of these so I can loop through each line and split everything? From here I'd also like to know how to add the numbers in a certain column together. I know I will probably have to use a for-loop to call every nth value(being the column #) and write an if statement to only take the values in the columns that are numbers by checking them through a parse statement and then add them.

Comment: You can make an Arraylist<Arraylist<String>> results and instead of adding the line you could add the arraylist wich contains the splitted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an `Arraylist<Arraylist<String>>` results and instead of adding the line you could add the arraylist wich contains the splitted string.

The code will look like this.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>():
while(input_file.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = input_file.nextLine();
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
    result.add(myList);
}
```

`result.get(0)` will contain an `ArrayList<String>` with the splitted string.

Answer (score 3):

```
try (Stream<String> fs = Files.lines(path)) {
  List<List<String>> linesByElements = fs
      .map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(",")))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```